# Pass bash variable to python command

Tags: python, bash, aix

I'm trying to do a basic password encryption script with two parameters but I can't make it work:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
set -x
trap read debug
export ppwd=$2;
export usr=$1;

pwd=$(python -c 'import crypt, os,base64; print crypt.crypt("str(os.environ['ppwd'])", "$6$"+base64.b64encode(os.urandom(24))+"$")');

echo $ppwd;
echo $usr:$pwd|chpasswd -ec
```

I tried using regular bash scripting variables, print os.environ['ppwd'] instead of str(os.environ['ppwd'].
The script it's supposed to change the password for AIX environment but it doesn't work.
It works if I do it manually using the python command and chpasswd. My guess is that it doesn't pass the variable to the python command..
Debug:

```
./sc.sh testuser MyPass134

+ trap read debug
++ read
+ export ppwd=MyPass134
+ ppwd=MyPass134
++ read
+ export usr=testuser
+ usr=testuser
++ read
++ python -c 'import crypt, os,base64; print 
crypt.crypt("str(os.environ[ppwd]", "$6$"+base64.b64encode(os.urandom(24))+"$")'
+ pwd=bbdf5picgZM4.
++ read
+ echo
++ read
+ echo testuser:bbdf5picgZM4.
++ read
+ chpasswd -ec
```

Comment: Do you just have a typo? `ppw` vs `ppwd`?

Comment: You set the *ppw* variable but you call `os.environ['ppwd']`. Is that a typo?

Comment: When you type `python -c 'import crypt ... "str(os.environ['ppwd'])"` . It is exactly the same as if you had typed `python -c 'import crypt ... "str(os.environ[ppwd])"` because the first single quote before `ppwd` closes the quote started by the first single quote after `-c`, and the two strings are concatenated.

Comment: Sorry guys, that was a typo, issue is still unsolved :(

Comment: I made more tests, commented the python command in the script, ran the command separately , replaced $ppwd manually in the script with username  as input and worked perfectly. So the issue, like I suspected, it doesn't substitute $ppwd correctly in the python command

Comment: As a hint, using the script above, the password is changed to <<str(os.environ['ppwd']>>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"str(os.environ['ppwd'])"` is just a string. If you want to pass in `os.environ['ppwd']` then that's what you have to say.

```
python -c 'import crypt, os,base64; print 
crypt.crypt(os.environ["ppwd"], "$6$"+base64.b64encode(os.urandom(24))+"$")'
```

An environment variable is already a string by definition, so the `str()` is entirely superfluous.

Also, you cannot nest single-quoted strings. I trivially switched to double quotes to fix that.

Putting the variable in the environment with `export` is a rather roundabout way of passing a string to Python. The best way would probably be a temporary pipe but making this properly secure is a significant undertaking.  Here's a simpler way to pass in a string:

```
python -c 'import crypt, os, base64, sys; 
    print(crypt.crypt(sys.argv[1], "$6$"+base64.b64encode(os.urandom(24))+"$"))' "password"
```

Finally, over in the shell script, you really should [quote your variables.](/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

```
echo "$ppwd"
echo "$usr:$pwd"|chpasswd -ec
```

Comment: You are right, @tripleee , I added the answer but somehow it wasn't saved... this is the correct answer. I used sys.argv[1]